# how to push the incoming details through registration for login to the localstorage in javascript

Tags: javascript

the problem to push data into localstorage from the array with objects , the details getted through textboxes  by registeration and login

how json used for this problem in javascript

```
<body  background="img.jpeg">
    <div><dr><a href="logon.html">LOGIN</a> <a class="a1" href="register.html">REGISTER</a></dr> </div>
    <div class="div1">
    <form id="log">
        <h1>LOGIN</h1>
        <label><b>USERNAME:</b></label><input type="text" name="Username" id="usrnme"><br><br>
        <label><b>PASSWORD:</b></label><input type="text" name="Password" id="pwd"><br><br>
        <label><b>EMAIL-ID:</b></label><input type="text" name="Email" id="mail"><br><br>
        <input type="button" value="Register" name="Register" onclick="register()">
    </form>
</div>
```

the result to store  the data to the local storage

Comment: Better take a look at this https://www.taniarascia.com/how-to-use-local-storage-with-javascript/

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can store data with two ways.

You can use the [setItem](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/setItem) function

```
localStorage.setItem(myKey, myValue);
```

or you can directly set those values via

```
localStorage.myKey = myValue;
```

If you want to receive values from the localstorage you can use **get** instead of set.

Please let me know if that already helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use, FormData,

```
<script>
let frm = document.querySelector("#log");

let data = new FormData(frm);

for (var [key, value] of data.entries()) { 
  localStorage.setItem(key, value);
}

// Finally you can get values from localStorage

localStorage.getItem("key");

</script>
```

Before run this code make sure form values are not empty.

Answer (score -1):

You need to create a JS file or `<script>` tag that can extract the values from the input field and use browser `localstorage` API to set the values.

Seeing that your code is still limited to just HTML and I do not know your level of knowledge in HTML and JS, I will add a code snippet to help you along the way:

```
...html stuff
<script>
  // JS code
</script>
```

Resources:

- Javascript get input value

  - https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_text_value.asp
- Localstorage

  - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage